# File transfer (.png , .txt) between Server and Client using UDP

Tags: java, server, ftp, udp, client

I wrote a server and client for client to connect to the server and select a data from the server's directory to transfer the data with UDP protocol but the problem is, it is only working for .txt files it isn't working for .png files and also in the .txt files the output files are not the same with the original one forexample lines between words are not there and all the words printed side by side instead of line by line. How can i fix this problem ?

Server side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class FTPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        DatagramPacket inPacket = null;
        DatagramPacket outPacket = null;
        byte[] inBuf, outBuf;
        String msg;
        final int PORT = 50000;

        try
        {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
            while(true) 
            {
            System.out.println("\nRunning...\n");

            inBuf = new byte[1000];
            inPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, inBuf.length);
            socket.receive(inPacket);

            int source_port=inPacket.getPort();
            InetAddress source_address = inPacket.getAddress();
            msg = new String(inPacket.getData(), 0, inPacket.getLength());
            System.out.println("CLient: " + source_address + ":" + source_port);

            String dirname  = "/home/erke/Desktop/data";
            File f1 = new File(dirname);
            File fl[] = f1.listFiles();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\n");
            int c=0;

            for(int i = 0;i<fl.length;i++)
            {
                if(fl[i].canRead())
                    c++;
            }

            sb.append(c+ " files found.\n\n");

            for(int i=0; i<fl.length;i++)
                    sb.append(fl[i].getName()+ " " + fl[i].length()+ " Bytes\n");

            sb.append("\nEnter file name to Download: ");
            outBuf = (sb.toString()).getBytes();
            outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, 0, outBuf.length, source_address, source_port);
            socket.send(outPacket);

            inBuf = new byte[1000];
            inPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, inBuf.length);
            socket.receive(inPacket);
            String filename = new String(inPacket.getData(), 0, inPacket.getLength());

            System.out.println("Requested File: " + filename);

            boolean flis = false;
            int index =-1;
            sb = new StringBuilder("");
            for(int i=0;i<fl.length;i++) 
            {
                    if(((fl[i].getName()).toString()).equalsIgnoreCase(filename))
                    {
                        index = i;
                        flis = true;

                    }
            }

            if(!flis) 
            {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                    sb.append("ERROR");
                    outBuf = (sb.toString()).getBytes();
                    outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, 0, outBuf.length, source_address, source_port);
                    socket.send(outPacket);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                        //File send
                        File ff=new File(fl[index].getAbsolutePath());
                        FileReader fr = new FileReader(ff);
                        BufferedReader brf = new BufferedReader(fr);
                        String s = null;
                        sb=new StringBuilder();

                        while((s=brf.readLine())!=null)
                        {
                            sb.append(s);
                        }

                        if(brf.readLine()==null)
                                System.out.println("File Read Succesfull, CLosing Socket");

                        outBuf=new byte[100000];
                        outBuf = (sb.toString()).getBytes();
                        outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, 0, outBuf.length,source_address, source_port);
                        socket.send(outPacket);

                } catch (Exception ioe) {
                    System.out.println(ioe);
                }

            }
            }


        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Client side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FTPClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        DatagramPacket inPacket = null;
        DatagramPacket outPacket = null;
        byte[] inBuf, outBuf;
        final int PORT = 50000;
        String msg = null;
        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);


        try
        {
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
                socket = new DatagramSocket();

                msg = "";
                outBuf =msg.getBytes();
                outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, 0, outBuf.length,address,PORT);
                socket.send(outPacket);

                inBuf = new byte[65535];
                inPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, inBuf.length);
                socket.receive(inPacket);

                String data = new String(inPacket.getData(), 0, inPacket.getLength());
                //Print file list
                System.out.println(data);

                //Send file name
                String filename = src.nextLine();
                outBuf = filename.getBytes();
                outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, 0, outBuf.length, address, PORT);
                socket.send(outPacket);

                //Receive file
                inBuf = new byte[100000];
                inPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, inBuf.length);
                socket.receive(inPacket);

                data = new String(inPacket.getData(), 0, inPacket.getLength());
                if(data.endsWith("ERROR"))
                {
                        System.out.println("File doesn't exists.\n");
                        socket.close();
                }

                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                            BufferedWriter pw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename)));
                            pw.write(data);
                            //Force write buffer to Fİle
                            pw.close();

                            System.out.println("File Write Succesful. Closing Socket");
                            socket.close();

                    } catch (Exception ioe) {
                        System.out.println("File Error\n");
                        socket.close();
                    }
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nNetwork Error. Try Again Later. \n");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using `String` to store file data in both client and the server. In order to be able to transfer any file other then a text file, in your server you should have a `byte[]` buffer instead of `String`, and use it for loading file contents. You can do this by using classes with names ending with `InputStream`. After you do that send those bytes over a network. Same goes for the client.

`InputStream` and `OutputStream` are used to read\write bytes from files directly, while `Reader` and `Writer` classes are specifically intended to work with text files. You cannot read\write bytes with these classes, they work only with characters and strings. You will still be able to transfer text files too though since they are also just an array of bytes.

Also you should be using TCP if you want to transfer your files without losing packets, which UDP tends to do as it doesn't have mechanisms to ensure that packets are safely delivered to a destination like TCP does.